# How to send a specific picture to whatsapp in my android application

Tags: android, shell, adb

Can someone please help me with this adb shell code needed to share a specific picture (screenshot I took) to what's app?

Here's the code I tried:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -t image/* -e stream storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/screen.png
```

When executed all I get is the android prompt to chose the app I want for sharing when selecting what's app sharing failed (I even tried another app like Instagram, same problem)